# How to auto-include a related model in devise's current_user helper method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

How can I add `:includes => :account` to the current_user finder method in devise ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :your, :devise, :modules
  default_scope :includes => :account
end
```

that will always include the account if you load the user.

Comment: Yes, but that would be for all purposes of User, not only devise ;) Anyway, that's a start, thanks

Comment: I know, but right now I have no idea how do this only for the current_user. But are there a lot of situation where you don't need the included account?

Comment: Yes, indedd, there are situations. But I'll use that until I find a better solution ;) thanks

Comment: Note that in Rails 3, the syntax would look like `default_scope includes(:account)`